# Error al mover array en C

Tags: array, c

Me gustaría poder mover un array a la derecha:

**Array original:**
1 2 3 4 5

**Array buscado:**
5 1 2 3 4

El código que tengo es:

```
// numero[] pasa el array con una serie de números pedidos antes
// size la cantidad de números que contiene el array anterior
void mover(int numero[], int size){
       int aux=numero[size-1];
       for(int i=1; i<size; i++){
            numero[i]=numero[i++];
       }
       numero[0]=aux;
}
```

**Array que sale con este código:**
5 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es moverlo comenzando por la derecha:

```
void mover(int numero[], int size) {

    int aux = numero[size - 1];
    for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        numero[i] = numero[i - 1];
    }
    numero[0] = aux;
}
```

**Comprobación**

```
void main() {
    int num[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    mover(num, sizeof (num) / sizeof (int));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (num) / sizeof (int); i++) {
        printf("%d", num[i]);
    }
}
```

produce

```
51234
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!